# Will Depth-first search benefit from Compressed Sparse Row storage?

Tags: depth-first-search, csr

I'm trying to speedup DFS method. As far as I know, the bottelneck lie in the memory/cache I/O. I want to know, if I transfer the graph to CSR(Compressed Sparse Row) format, will DFS benefit from it?